# Syntax highlighter editor in github

Tags: github

I am very new to github.
I have recently added a repository project in the github and have added description pages website too from the layout provided by github.

Now I want to put my content to the pages including code examples etc.
But when I edit the page, it gives me very simple editor to edit the page.

Is there any editor available in github that can provide me syntax highlighting feature for the code I examples?

Comment: Are you looking for a way to edit files *directly in the GitHub web interface* with syntax highlighting? Most developers `clone` a repository to their local machine and use whatever tools they want there (e.g. Vim, Emacs, Sublime Text, Visual Studio).

Comment: *GitHub* use syntax highlighting only during rendering the already push/stored files into its repository. So you need to edit the file locally on your pc, and the proper editor you wish, and the just push it into *Github*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*GitHub* use syntax highlighting only during rendering the already pushed or stored files into the defined repository. So in order to change the view of the file, you have to edit the file locally on your *pc* with the proper editor you wish, then just add the file to the *git* index, commit the changes into the defined git repository, and push it into *GitHub*. And you'll see the changes.

However, there is the editor embedded into *GitHub*, which has not so bad features as a text editor, even highlightning. For example, here is [a ruby library file](https://github.com/znamenica/slavic/edit/master/lib/slavic/slovo.rb) in the edit mode. As you can see, it keywords are highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

> GitHub use syntax highlighting only during rendering the already pushed or stored files into the defined repository

Actually... since Feb. 2021 (7 years later), you now have what the OP wants:

[Nat Friedman](https://twitter.com/natfriedman/) (CEO of GitHub) announces it [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/natfriedman/status/1365709647911395332):

> Another tiny but nice improvement we just shipped to GitHub – **syntax highlighting now works on new files without the need to commit first.**
>
> [image: Syntax Highlighting]